# MySQL left join with extra clauses returns unmatched rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a translations table

```
id | language | tr_text | orig_id
```

the orig_id serves to reference the original text e.g.

```
id | language | tr_text | orig_id
 1 | EN | Hello | 1
 2 | EN | Bye | 2
 3 |DE | Hallo | 1
```

Now I am trying to produce a query that gives me all of the original terms and all of the translated ones, with nulls where a translation has not be entered:

```
SELECT TransOrg.id, TransOrg.tr_text, TransOrg.tr_Language, TransLang.id, TransLang.tr_text, TransLang.tr_Language
FROM Translations AS TransOrg
LEFT JOIN Translations AS TransLang
ON TransOrg.id = TransLang.orig_id
AND TransOrg.Language = 'EN' AND TransLang.Language = 'DE'
```

This however returns what I want plus the DE translations:

```
1 | Hello | EN | 3 | Hallo | DE
2 | Bye | EN | null | null | null  
3 | Hallo | DE | null | null | null  < why is this here?!
```

I thought the

```
AND TransOrg.Language = 'EN'
```

condition would have stopped this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `TransOrg.Language = 'EN'` in `WHERE` clause to prevent it from showing in the result set.

```
SELECT TransOrg.id, TransOrg.tr_text, TransOrg.tr_Language, TransLang.id,
  TransLang.tr_text, TransLang.tr_Language
 FROM Translations AS TransOrg
 LEFT JOIN Translations AS TransLang
 ON (TransOrg.id = TransLang.orig_id AND TransLang.Language = 'DE')
 WHERE TransOrg.Language = 'EN';
```

Comment: I tried adding a where clause but it kept giving me an error, could you show me where the clause should go. Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer. That should give you all English originals as well as all DE translations, if they exist.